# How do I use efficient repeats in sheets for pop music?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, musical-forms, musescore, repeats

I'm transcribing some music with the following structure:

`Intro AB AC AB AC Outro`

How in can I notate this structure with repeats and codas? Or do I just have to write it all out?
I'm using MuseScore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try something like this, using just [repeat signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeat_sign) and [volta brackets](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/3/voltas):

```
               |-1.,3.-|-2.,4.-|
|| intro ||: A |  B   :|| C   :|| outro ||
```

Comment: If the parts are relatively simple, you could even print  the B-line and C-line in the same measures, with the "1,3" and "2,4" annotated next to each.  It's a style and readability choice.